# Native Script app emulation

Tags: angular, react-native, nativescript

I am developing a project in NativeScript. My office PC is 32 bit and can not run Genymotion. The android emulator is slow like hell. Considering the road blocks - what are the alternatives to emulate + test + debug Native Script app during development ?

Comment: The android emulator and this - https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: for further help you could also review the article here - http://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/android-virtual-devices

Comment: @BradMartin Thank you so much. I used the intel's HAXM and it worked fine on my 64 bit system. Now installing on the 32 bit system

Comment: @NikolayTsonev Thanks a ton. The documentation link is really helpful.